# Joinning two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to resolve next issue:
we have two tables without any relation between them. First of them contents some info about few objects. Something like that

```
create table properties
(
    obj1_prop1 varchar(10),
    obj1_prop2 varchar(10),
    obj1_prop3 varchar(10),
    obj2_prop1 varchar(10),
    obj2_prop2 varchar(10),
    obj2_prop3 varchar(10),
    obj3_prop1 varchar(10),
    obj3_prop2 varchar(10),
    obj3_prop3 varchar(10),
    obj4_prop1 varchar(10),
    obj4_prop2 varchar(10),
    obj4_prop3 varchar(10),
    id int not null,
    primary key (id)
)
```

Every of this object consists of smaller objects (each of them has some extra property). We have no info about smaller objects' quantity. This info stores in the second table, something like that

```
create table parts
(
    obj_id int not null,
    prop1 varchar(10),
    prop2 varchar(10),
    prop3 varchar(10),
    extra_prop varchar(10)
)
```

What query should I use to get data from this tables in format like first table has this `extra_prop` column. Result should be look like we have a table with next fields:

```
create table properties
(
    obj1_prop1 varchar(10),
    obj1_prop2 varchar(10),
    obj1_prop3 varchar(10),
    obj1_extra_prop varchar(10),
    obj2_prop1 varchar(10),
    obj2_prop2 varchar(10),
    obj2_prop3 varchar(10),
    obj2_extra_prop varchar(10),
    obj3_prop1 varchar(10),
    obj3_prop2 varchar(10),
    obj3_prop3 varchar(10),
    obj3_extra_prop varchar(10),
    obj4_prop1 varchar(10),
    obj4_prop2 varchar(10),
    obj4_prop3 varchar(10),
    obj4_extra_prop varchar(10),
    id int not null,
    primary key (id)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add obj_id reference column in to your properties table. So ideally you will end up having 4 of such fields. Then you can join.

```
create table properties
(
    obj1_id int,
    obj1_prop1 varchar(10),
obj1_prop2 varchar(10),
obj1_prop3 varchar(10),
obj2_id int,
obj2_prop1 varchar(10),
obj2_prop2 varchar(10),
obj2_prop3 varchar(10),
obj3_id int,
obj3_prop1 varchar(10),
obj3_prop2 varchar(10),
obj3_prop3 varchar(10),
obj4_id int,
obj4_prop1 varchar(10),
obj4_prop2 varchar(10),
obj4_prop3 varchar(10),
id int not null,
primary key (id)
)
```

Then you can join as follows

```
SELECT *[set your columns here] FROM properties AS p 
LEFT OUTER JOIN parts AS p1 ON p1.obj_id = p.obj1_id  
LEFT OUTER JOIN parts AS p2 ON p2.obj_id = p.obj2_id  
LEFT OUTER JOIN parts AS p3 ON p3.obj_id = p.obj3_id  
LEFT OUTER JOIN parts AS p4 ON p4.obj_id = p.obj4_id
```